# Finding a probability expression when tossing balls into boxes.

Tags: probability, problem-solving, factorial

In an experiment, I am tossing $n$ balls at 10 boxes. The balls are equally likely (1/10) to land in any of the ten boxes. I have an expression for the probability that after throwing $n$ balls, at least one box contains at least 2 balls. I want to find $n$ such that this probability is exactly 1/2.

I would like to first say I am not great at solving problem containing factorials. Instead of find the probability of a box having at least 2 balls in it, I found the complement which is the probability of each box having less than 2 balls in it.

Sample Space |$S_n$| = $10^n$

Pr(A) = 1 - Pr($\overline A$)
and |$\overline A$| = ${\frac{10!}{(10-n)!}}$
Pr($\overline A$) = ${\frac{\frac{10!}{(10-n)!}}{10^n}}$

I am trying to solve Pr(A) = 1/2

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Can you explain the problem clearly?  I gather there are $10$ boxes and some balls being thrown at them.  Can you add more detail?

Comment: @lulu I added an edit explaining, sorry

Comment: Make a useful title.  Yours is completely vacuous and could apply to nearly every posting on this site.

Comment: So:  you have $10$ boxes and $n$ balls, yes?  Let's say $A_n$ is the event that there is at least one box with at least $2$ balls.  This depends on $n$ so it is good to put the $n$ in the event name.   Are you saying that $P(A_n)=1 - \frac {10!}{(10-n)!\times 10^n}$?  Or something else?

Comment: @lulu The Pr($\overline A$) was wrong and I fixed it, I am just trying to solve the Pr(A) = 1/2, so solving for n

Comment: I was using the current version of your formula.

Comment: @lulu Yes your Pr($A_n$) is right, so I am trying to solve how many throws to throw to get 0.5 probability or higher

Comment: Ok, well you have an explicit formula.  So, just compute it for $n=1,2,3,\cdots...$ .  What's the problem?

Comment: Any method for solving this is going to be numerical, and there are so few values here that I can't imagine anything easier than just plugging in a few values.

Comment: Well... for $n\geq 11$ by the pigeon-hole principle we know that there *must* be at least one box with at least two balls in it, so if you do decide to resort to brute force by tabulating the probabilities you know that it can be done in a relatively short amount of time.

Comment: @lulu I would rather learn how to solve the function instead of trying multiple n, even though n has to be an integer

Comment: @JMoravitz True, but I am trying to figure it out what is the lowest number of throws to get a probability of 1/2 or higher

Comment: I think that is an error.  There isn't going to be a simpler version of this function, though of course you could use Stirling's approximation or such to estimate a solution...but that is more computer intense then just trying values.  Like I say, any solution is going to have a numerical component.

Comment: An $n=4, P(A) = 1 - \frac {9\cdot 8\cdot 7}{1000} = \frac {496}{1000}$

Comment: @DougM That is less than 1/2, but I understand that I can just input values of n and get the value I want. What I was trying to learn is solving the function for a specific value of Pr(A) = 1/2.

Comment: @ayejay the factorial operation generally doesn't play nicely, and are no elementary algebraic methods to isolate $n$ in any equation where $n!$ appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the complement event: $B=$*all boxes have one or zero balls*.  If you toss $n=11$ balls into ten boxes, then by the pigeonhole principle, $B$ is impossible. On the other hand, if $n=1$, then $B$ is certain.  As you increase $n$, the probability of $B$ should go down monotonically. From these facts, we know that the proability $P(B)=1/2$ occurs somewhere between $n=1$ and $n=11$.

Let's consider general $n$: we toss $n$ balls into ten boxes. $B$ occurs just when every ball goes into a different box. Disregarding the order in which we toss the balls, there are $10 \choose n$ ways to put $n$ indistinguishable balls into ten boxes that way. There are $10^n$ total ways to put balls into boxes, or $10^n/n!$ since again we're disregarding the order. Thus the probability of $B$ is:

$$P(B) = \frac{{10 \choose n}}{10^n/n!} = \frac{10!}{n! (10-n)!}\frac{n!}{10^n} = \frac{10!}{(10-n)! \;10^n}$$

The pattern is this:

$$P(B) = \frac{10}{10}\times \frac{9}{10} \times \frac{8}{10} \times \cdots \times \frac{10-[n-1]}{10}$$

which makes it easy to guess and check the answer, because $P(B_{n+1}) = P(B_{n}) \times \frac{10-n}{10}$.

If we plug in $n=4$, we find that

$$P(B) = \frac{10!}{6!} \frac{1}{10^4} = \frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7}{10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10} = \frac{9\cdot 7}{5\cdot 5\cdot 5} = \frac{63}{125} = 0.504$$
which is an exact answer. Then $P(A) = 0.496$.